# AIR application interacting with C# application on desktop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have an AIR application, which must somehow interact with C# application on desktop, ( it must generally receive data which C# application extracted from MSSQL database ).

- Is it possible this interaction and how ?

Comment: You can also check NativeProcess class , it also allow to transfer data between AIR and native C# app: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of ways. the most simple is to connect a tcpip connection, and communicate the data via localhost. this way you'll later be able to move the app.

```
public function connectToServer(ip:String="127.0.0.1", port:Number=65045):void {
        trace("connect")
        theSocket=new Socket(ip, port);
        theSocket.connect(ip,port);
        theSocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerrorEvent)
        theSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA,Getdata);
        theSocket.timeout=10*60*60*1000 //10 minutes
    }
```

i suppose you'll know the c# side.

also you can make a file what both apps will read/write, you can use extensions, so one app will be contained by the other, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You could bake in some native code libraries into your AIR app to talk to the other app or even better, take the functionality of that C# app merge it as native code into your AIR app so you can talk to MySQL directly. Good Luck!

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html